# SharePoint 2010 users/groups over REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Is there a way to retrieve a list of site users/groups via REST similar to how you can get list data using the listdata.svc? I would like to fetch a list of all users and groups on the site so that I can have an input where the user enters a name (ex John Smith) and then I can map that name to the relevent user ID (ex John Smith's ID:3) to be used when pushing updates to the list item since you must use the ID for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  Here is teh codez using rest.

Groups Only:

```
[Site]/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=substringof('SharePointGroup',ContentType) eq true
```

People Only:

```
[Site]/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=substringof('Person',ContentType) eq true
```

Both:

```
[Site]/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/UserInformationList
```

With any of these methods you will be able to get the id and more

```
<m:properties>
  <d:ContentTypeID>0x010....</d:ContentTypeID>
  <d:Name>Doe, John</d:Name>
  <d:Account>ABC\john.doe</d:Account>
  <d:WorkEMail>jd@abc.com</d:WorkEMail>
  <d:MobilePhone m:null="true" />
  <d:AboutMe m:null="true" />
  <d:SIPAddress m:null="true" />
  <d:IsSiteAdmin m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsSiteAdmin>
  <d:Deleted m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Deleted>
  <d:Picture m:null="true" />
  <d:Department m:null="true" />
  <d:Title m:null="true" />
  <d:FirstName>John</d:FirstName>
  <d:LastName>Doe</d:LastName>
  <d:UserName>John.Doe</d:UserName>
  <d:WebSite m:null="true" />
  <d:AskMeAbout m:null="true" />
  <d:WorkPhone>8885551212</d:WorkPhone>
  <d:Office m:null="true" />
  <d:Unit m:null="true" />
  <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
  <d:ContentType>Person</d:ContentType>
  <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-09-27T00:00:19</d:Modified>
  <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2013-10-17T12:13:59</d:Created>
  <d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:CreatedById>
  <d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1073741823</d:ModifiedById>
  <d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">217</d:Owshiddenversion>
  <d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
  <d:Path>/sites/test/_catalogs/users</d:Path>
</m:properties>
```

Comment: Hi Joe,
How to fetch list of users from sharepoint group using listdata.svc, Any help ?